# Print adjacent cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to print adjacent cell values from column 2 with reference to my duplicated values (various). Suppose a number which have been repeated several times I want to print those adjacent values of those duplicated values horizontally and then move to next to find other duplicated values and so on. I have used do loop function but couldn't get the desired result

A full code for this

```
Dim k As Integer 
Dim a As Integer
Dim d As Integer
a = 2
d = 18
For k = 2 To 11000
    'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    'If Worksheets(5).Cells(k, 6).Value <> Worksheets(5).Cells(k + 1, 6) Then
    'Worksheets(5).Cells(a, d).Value = Worksheets(5).Cells(a, 2).Value
    If Worksheets(5).Cells(k, 15).Value = Worksheets(5).Cells(k, 12) Then
        Worksheets(5).Cells(a, d).Value = Worksheets(5).Cells(a, 2).Value
    ElseIf Worksheets(5).Cells(k, 15).Value <> Worksheets(5).Cells(k + 1, 12) Then
        Worksheets(5).Cells(a, d).Value = Worksheets(5).Cells(a, 2).Value
        'a = a + 1
        k = k + 1
        'd = d + 1
    End If
Next k
```

Comment: What specific problem did you have getting your attempt to work?

Comment: It is giving me all the values of the column 2.. Not segregating the values

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you included your code in your question. That way others can try it without having to guess.

Comment: Sure.. I ll do that

Comment: Dim k As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim d As Integer
a = 2
d = 18
For k = 2 To 11000
'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
'If Worksheets(5).Cells(k, 6).Value <> Worksheets(5).Cells(k + 1, 6) Then
'Worksheets(5).Cells(a, d).Value = Worksheets(5).Cells(a, 2).Value
If Worksheets(5).Cells(k, 15).Value = Worksheets(5).Cells(k, 12) Then Worksheets(5).Cells(a, d).Value = Worksheets(5).Cells(a, 2).Value
ElseIf Worksheets(5).Cells(k, 15).Value <> Worksheets(5).Cells(k + 1, 12) Then
Worksheets(5).Cells(a, d).Value = Worksheets(5).Cells(a, 2).Value
'a = a + 1
k = k + 1
'd = d + 1
End If
Next k

Comment: Please include the code in your question by editing it. As you can see, code can not be properly formatted in a comment.

Comment: pasted in the comment

Comment: It's still unclear to me what exactly you're going for. Did you mean to use `Worksheets(5).Cells(k, d).Value = Worksheets(5).Cells(a, 2).Value` so when you do have a duplicate, the value of the second column of that row is placed in the 18th column? Because now it's just getting overwritten. Also, why is `k` getting incremented in the `ElseIf` ?